# Delete a column from a table without changing the environment

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm working on Oracle SQL database, quite big database. One of (among 150 tables) this table has to be changed because it's redundant (it can be generated through a join). I have been asked to delete a column from this table, to get rid of the redundancy. The problem is that now I have to change code everywhere someone made a insert/update/etc on this table (and don't forget the constraint!). I thought "I can make a view that do the right join" so the problem it's solved for all the select, but it's not working for the insert, because I'm updating 2 tables... Is there a way to solve this problem?

My goal is to rename my original table `original_table` in `original_table_smaller` (with one less column) and create a `view` (or something like a view) called `original_table` that work like the original table.

Is this possible?

Comment: As far as I know it's not possible to do `insert`, `update` or `delete` on views. Just `select` is allowed.

Comment: Yes that's possible but the existing code that does the insert/update/delete will fail (you can't insert/update/delete rows on a view).

Comment: @LinusCaldwell of course you can make updatetable views, e.g. using an `instead of` Trigger.

Comment: Well, obviously I was wrong. Just forget my previous comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As your view will contain one column that is not present in the real table, you will need to use an `instead of` trigger to make the view updateable.

Something like this:

```
create table smaller_table 
(
   id integer not null primary key, 
   some_column varchar(20)
);

create view real_table 
as 
select id,
       some_column,
       null as old_column
from smaller_table;
```

Now your old code would run something like this:

```
insert into real_table 
  (id, some_column, old_column)
values
  (1, 'foo', 'bar');
```

which results in:

> ORA-01733: virtual column not allowed here

To get around this, you need an `INSTEAD OF` trigger:

```
create or replace trigger comp_trigger 
   instead of insert on smaller_table
begin
  insert into old_table 
    (id, some_column)
  values
    (:new.id, :new.some_column);
end;
/
```

Now the value for the "old_column" will be ignored. You need something similar for updates as well.

If your view contains a join, then you can handle that situation as well in the trigger. Simply do an update/insert according to the data to two different tables

For more details and examples, see the manual
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#i1006376

Comment: INSTEAD OF trigger was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to insert/update on views.
You might want to check with USER_UPDATABLE_COLUMNS which columns you can insert to the view.

Check with this query:

```
select * from user_updatable_columns where table_name = 'VIEW_NAME';
```

Oracle has two different ways of making views updatable:-

1. The view is "key preserved" with respect to what you are trying to update. This means the primary key of the underlying table is in the view and the row appears only once in the view. This means Oracle can figure out exactly which underlying table row to update OR
2. You write an instead of trigger.